# How can I change the default http port defininition of Omnibus Gitlab?

Tags: centos, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

While I install Omnibus Gitlab package, I want to change the default Http port configuration. Because the default http port configuration is 80, I have use it for my website, so I want to change it to another port. I modify the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb, I changed the 80 ports to other values, then run gitlab-ctl reconfigure, the gitlab still monitor 80 port.

Why my change didn't take any effect?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `nginx['listen_port'] = 81` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`?

If this doesn't work another option is to disable the Omnibus Nginx entirely and add a new configuration to your existing web server to proxy requests to GitLab. The advantage to this route is your clients would not need to know to use port 81 instead of port 80.

To disable the bundled Nginx use `nginx['enable'] = false` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`. See [Omnibus documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#configuration) for more details.